# sum of arraylist elements getted by cursor

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, cursor

I've a table of Holidays, I'm trying to check if some specific one took any holidays before

This is my table construction:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Holidays (HolidayID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Department TEXT NOT NULL, Profession TEXT NOT NULL, EmpName TEXT NOT NULL, DaysofHoliday TEXT NOT NULL, StartDay TEXT NOT NULL, StartMonth TEXT NOT NULL, StartYear TEXT NOT NULL, EndDay TEXT, EndMonth TEXT, EndYear TEXT, PresentedDay TEXT NOT NULL, PresentedMonth TEXT NOT NULL, PresentedYear TEXT NOT NULL, Engineer TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveDay TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveMonth TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveYear TEXT NOT NULL)")
```

My companion object:

```
companion object {
    val DB_Name = "samalout.db"
    val TABLE_HOL = "Holidays"
    val COL_41 = "HolidayID"
    val COL_42 = "Department"
    val COL_43 = "Profession"
    val COL_44 = "EmpName"
    val COL_45 = "DaysofHoliday"
    val COL_46 = "StartDay"
    val COL_47 = "StartMonth"
    val COL_48 = "StartYear"
    val COL_49 = "EndDay"
    val COL_410 = "EndMonth"
    val COL_411 = "EndYear"
    val COL_412 = "PresentedDay"
    val COL_413 = "PresentedMonth"
    val COL_414 = "PresentedYear"
    val COL_415 = "Engineer"
    val COL_416 = "ApproveDay"
    val COL_417 = "ApproveMonth"
    val COL_418 = "ApproveYear"
}
```

This my search function:

```
fun Game() {
    var query1 = ""
    var rv = ArrayList<String>()
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    query1 = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_HOL + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COL_44 + "='" + spin3.selectedItem.toString() + "'"
    val c1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null)
    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(c1.getString(0))
        textView13.text = rv.sum().toString()
    }
}
```

Edit:
sum function can't b done to arraylist of strings, so I tried something else:

```
while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(c1.getString(0))
        for (item in rv)
            println(item)
    }
```

but also it didn't get me result

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I think the question is not really clear, at least to me. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: The table is to store data of holidays, employees takes holidays in a company, each saved holiday has a value of days of holidays taken by the employee, I wanna retrive how many holidays that employee taken.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, It's the Column that I search .. I performed a select query on adb, it returned different columns .. for clarity: I assigned the following columns (HolidayID, Department, Profession, EmpName), when I made a select * from table Holidays; on adb it returned the following (HolidayID, EmpName, Department, Profession) .. I don't know what happened to reverse my initials but I changed search query in main activity to the second column of table and it worked for me.

Edit: It was the insertion statement, it's all my fault

```
fun insertDataHol(holid: Int, department: String, profession: String, empname: String, daysofholiday: String, startday: String, startmonth: String, startyear: String, endday: String, endmonth: String, endyear: String, presentedday: String, presentedmonth: String, presentedyear: String, engineer: String, approveday: String, approvemonth: String, approveyear: String) {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(COL_41, holid)
    contentValues.put(COL_42, empname)
    contentValues.put(COL_43, department)
    contentValues.put(COL_44, profession)
    contentValues.put(COL_45, daysofholiday)
    contentValues.put(COL_46, startday)
    contentValues.put(COL_47, startmonth)
    contentValues.put(COL_48, startyear)
    contentValues.put(COL_49, endday)
    contentValues.put(COL_410, endmonth)
    contentValues.put(COL_411, endyear)
    contentValues.put(COL_412, presentedday)
    contentValues.put(COL_413, presentedmonth)
    contentValues.put(COL_414, presentedyear)
    contentValues.put(COL_415, engineer)
    contentValues.put(COL_416, approveday)
    contentValues.put(COL_417, approvemonth)
    contentValues.put(COL_418, approveyear)
    db.insert(TABLE_HOL, null, contentValues)
}
```

In the insert statement I defined to insert name as the second column, so it's my fault I tried to retrieve name from the forth column while it's inserted in second column.